# Question regarding the clock() function

Tags: visual-c++

Why does the time to execute function f1() changes from one run to another in debug mode? Why it's always zero in release mode?

I didn't include stdio.h nor cstdio and the code compiled. How ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void f1()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ );
}

int main()
{
    clock_t start, finish;

    start = clock();
    for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) f1();
    finish = clock();

    double duration = (double)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf( "Duration = %6.2f seconds\n", duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason you are seeing zero runtime for `f1()` in release mode is because the compiler is optimizing the function. Since your `for` loop doesn't have a code block, it can effectively be pulled out during compilation.

I'm guessing that this optimization is not performed in debug mode, which would explain why you see a longer execution time. It varies between runs simply because your OS scheduler (almost certainly) does not guarantee a fixed time slot for processes.

As for why you can use `printf()` when you have not explicitly included `<cstdio>`, it's because of the `<iostream>` include.

From looking my headers at **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include**, I can see that *iostream* includes *istream* and *ostream*, both of which include *ios*, which includes *xlocnum*, which includes both *cstdlib* and *cstdio*.

Comment: I changed the function f1() to calculate the sum of the first 10000 ints and to return this value. The release mode still returns 0 for the executiuon time.

Comment: I finally found a situation where the execution time in release mode is grater than 0.

Comment: @jaayrosa, I'm not sure my assumption about compiler optimization was correct, but it's probable for an empty loop. If you still were seeing 0 runtime with an instruction in the loop, it's likely something else was going on (see hopia's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Possible  the machine you're running your test code from is too fast.  Try increasing the loop count to a really huge number.

Other things to try is to test with the sleep() function. 
This should confirm the behavior of your clock() measurements.

Comment: Any chance you could make a small edit? I missed your comment about testing with `sleep()` and I want to change my vote. Sorry.

Comment: No prob.  I was thinking to provide some debugging tips on how to determine if his clock() is working properly.  But yes, I agree optimizations may convert that loop to do nothing.